# Nunit : Unit test a value dependent on other value

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, nunit

In json file (It is used as config file for application)

```
{
   val1 : true,
   val2 : true
}
```

val2 can be true, only if val1 is true.
Since it is not a good practice to write if statement or any other logic in unit test,
how to verify val2 values for different json files.

Comment: Why do you want to "test" json files? I could understand if you wanted to test a validation code. But _data files_?

Comment: it is required to provide safety.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, sorry. Can you elaborate a little? So you have a couple of json data files that look like the above? They are resources in your app and cannot be changed or added to by the user at runtime?

Comment: ^^ The point being: I'd have a validation code that runs on deserialization of the json. Then you could test the validation to pass on certain combinations _and fail_ on certain combinations. Then you can have another test that runs all the json files through that validation and all of them have to pass. If all of those tests pass: you're good. Am I missing something?

Comment: Since these json files are very important for application so in future if any developer tries to change it, so for that safety purpose such unit test is required.

Comment: _"these json files are very important for application so in future if any developer tries to change it"_ ok, so I infer, these are some kind of configs and you need regression test - or some sort of that. I'd really go for a little validation helper, that first is tested itself, then used to validate the files.

Comment: BTW: Outside unit tests, you may also consider protecting the files on the source code management level. For example [auto-reject changes through git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)? So if they are ever needed to change one would really have to know what they are doing and do it on purpose. You cannot "accidentally" disengage this protection...